# Pass row data from CSV to API and append results to an empty CSV column

Tags: python, csv

I'm attempting to write a code in Python that will take the rows from a `CSV` file and pass them to an API call. If there is a successful return, I'd like to append `yes` to the `match` column that I added. If no data is returned, append `no` instead.

[image]

This is the current code to return the matching results of the first row:

```py
headers = {
   'Authorization': {token},
   'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
}

data = '[{
    "name": "Company 1",
    "email_domain": "email1.com",
    "url": "https://www.url1.com"
}]'

response = requests.post(
    'https://{base_url}/api/match',
    headers=headers,
    data=data
)
```

This code is working for each row if I manually pass in the data to the API call, but since there are hundreds of rows, I'd like to be able to iterate through each row, pass them through the API call, and append `yes` or `no` to the `match` column that I created. My strong suit is not writing `for` loops, which I believe is the way to attack this, but would love any input from someone who has done something similar.

Comment: Please, avoid [posting images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). It is a better practice to transcribe them instead.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to iterate over your csv file, you will have to use a for loop. The csv.DictReader can convert a csv file in a list of dictionaries which is exactly what you need:

```
import csv
with open('filename.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        data = str([row])
```

alternatively you can use `pandas.DataFrame.to_json(orient="index")`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a `src.csv` file with the following contents:

```
company_id,company_name,url,company_domain,match
1,Company 1,https://www.url1.com,email1.com,
2,Company 2,https://www.url2.com,email2.io,
3,Company 3,https://www.url3.com,email3.com,
```

The following code snippet will read it and create a new `tgt.csv` file with the column `match` of each row set to `yes` or `no`, based on the results of the `request.post()` (you need to adjust it for your logic though):

```py
import csv
import json

token = 'Your API Token Here'
base_url = 'https://some.base.url'
headers = {
   'Authorization': token,
   'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
}

with open('src.csv') as src, open('tgt.csv', 'w', newline='') as tgt:
    reader = csv.reader(src)
    writer = csv.writer(tgt)

    columns = next(reader)

    writer.writerow(columns)

    for company_id, company_name, url, company_domain, match in reader:
        data = json.dumps([{
            'name': company_name,
            'email_domain': company_domain,
            'url': url
        }])

        response = requests.post(
            f'{base_url}/api/match',
            headers=headers,
            data=data
        )

        if response.ok:
            match = 'yes'
        else:
            match = 'no'

        writer.writerow((company_id, company_name, url, company_domain, match))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly. I appreciate the quick help!